# Spellcheck in TinyMCE without PHP/.NET?

Tags: tinymce, spell-checking

We would like to use the TinyMCE spellcheck function but *without* having to install PHP or .NET.

Has anyone successfully done this?

We are currently using Windows Server 2008, IIS 7 and Perl.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write some handler on your web server that expects the same parameters that the PHP script expects. What language you use for that doesn't matter. You'll need to do a little bit of reverse engineering and maybe change the URL in the Javascript to point to your new handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass gecko_spellcheck: true as an option to tinymce.init(), which will allow the browser to do the spellcheck.

It doesn't work with Internet Explorer, which makes sense since Internet Explorer doesn't have spell check embedded.

Comment: unfortunatly this will only work with the gecko enginge (Firefox browser)